# Hierarchical Data In TreeView. Find an node in tree

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tree, treeview

I have a `TreeView` in which I display Hierarchical Data.

### Model

```
class Node : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Node> Nodes { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Node>();
}
```

Storage of the nodes:

```
class NodesStorage : ObservableCollection<Node>
{
    public NodesStorage()
    {
        var node = new Node { Name = "1" };
        node.Nodes.Add(new Node { Name = "1a" });
        node.Nodes.Add(new Node { Name = "1b" });
        node.Nodes.Add(new Node { Name = "1c" });

        var node1 = new Node { Name = "2" };
        node1.Nodes.Add(new Node { Name = "2a" });
        node1.Nodes.Add(new Node { Name = "2b" });
        node1.Nodes.Add(new Node { Name = "2c" });

        this.Add(node);
        this.Add(node1);
    }
}
```

### ViewModel

```
class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Nodes = new NodesStorage();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Node> Nodes;
}
```

### View

```
<!--... Set DataContext ...-->

<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Nodes}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Nodes}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>

<!--...-->
```

### Question

And now I want to make the method that returns `true`, if the tree contains the node with the folowing name and `false` in another case:

```
public static bool IsTreeContains(Node node, string itemName)
{
    if (node.Name == itemName)
        return true;

    foreach (var n in node.Nodes)
    {
        return IsTreeContains(n, itemName);
    }

    // And what should I write here?
}
```

I think I can use backtracking here. But it's a realy bad idea.
What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with your recursive method:

```
foreach (var n in node.Nodes)
{
    return IsTreeContains(n, itemName);
}
```

That `returns` makes that the loop is only executed once.

Here is my code:

```
public static bool IsTreeContains(Node node, string itemName)
{
    if (node.Name == itemName)
        return true;

    foreach (var n in node.Nodes)
    {
        if(IsTreeContains(n, itemName))
            return true;          
    }

    return false;
}
```

**First** exit condition, then if the item is found stop iterating, if not, continue iterating. **Finally** if the node and every n-child is different of the item searched, return `false`.

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 3):

I could sense that you are doing "kind of" Depth First Search in the Tree.

To escape the recursion, you need two conditions in success and in failure and the result has to be propagated to the caller through recursion.

```
public static bool IsTreeContains(Node node, string itemName)
{
    // If the current Node matches
    if (node.Name == itemName)
        return true;

    // End of the Tree or the Node Collection
    if (node.Nodes.Count == 0)
        return false;

    foreach (var n in node.Nodes)
    {
        if (IsTreeContains(n, itemName))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I think I just completed your solution, but there are many ways to solve this algorithmically.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**
Corrected the correct algorithm based on the comments.

**EDIT 1:**
Corrected the loop runs only on the First Child Node. Thanks @BionicCode.

Comment: Your algorithm is a Depth-first search using Pre-order traversal. Breadth-first traverses level by level and is preferably implemented using a queue (iterative version).

Comment: Just wanted to upvote your answer as I saw a flaw in your algorithm. You are currently breaking out after the first iteration by using the `return` statment without a conditional check. This way iteration _always_ stops after the first child node. The code must be: `foreach(...) { if (IsTreeContains(n, itemName)) return true; }` (`else` continue `foreach`). Please fix it so that I can revert the downvote and upvote your answer. Also by applyig this changes this code won't compile without adding a `return false` to the tail of the method (in case `IsTreeContains` failed on all children failed).

Comment: Yes. I now realize that. I just went with a test cases of each node having one node under it, so it went though. Sorry for that and thanks for explaining :)